# Determining the return type of a class method without warning on gcc

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I would like to alias a return type for a templated class method, on clang I use

```
template <class R, unsigned int BlockSize>
struct block {
    using KeyType = decltype(((R*)nullptr)->getKey());
}
```

This works fine on clang, but on gcc 11.3.0 I get a warning:

```
 warning: ‘this’ pointer is null [-Wnonnull]
```

My question is what is the proper way to get the KeyType without warning?

Comment: Use `decltype(std::declval<R>().getKey())`?

Comment: @Osyotr Make that an answer, it's the correct solution imho.

Comment: Indeed this should be the answer, see: https://godbolt.org/z/cchhYYGMW

Comment: Although, `decltype`'s operand is unevaluated, so I don't really see why there should be a warning for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be able to use member functions in unevaluated contexts such as `decltype` expressions one should use `std::declval`:

```cpp
template <class R, unsigned int BlockSize>
struct block {
    using KeyType = decltype(std::declval<R>().getKey());
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is perfect, and a good deal less hacky.